# Adding and removing imaage view to window subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, subview

I am working with iPhone app(LandscapeRight Mode), I have added a Image view named imageView on my first page, but I have to delete it again on Third and fourth page. Please remember that I have to add this image again on Fifth page.

I added image with following code on first page :

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_logo_medium.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(123, 200, 250, 66);
imageView.tag = 800;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
//imageView.window.
[self.parentViewController.view.window addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

How this can be removed and re-added ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to remove `imageView` from its superview call:

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

keep in mind that `imageView` receives a `release` when removed, so you need to ensure that it is properly `retain`ed if you plan to reuse it. In other words, you will need to add an ivar to your controller class where you can retain the imageView for reuse. Actually you assign it to a local variable and at the end of the method you release; the variable should not be local, but a controller's ivar so to have persistence, and you will need to release it in your controller's `dealloc`.

EDIT:

I suppose that you have a `UIViewController` somewhere that can manage adding and removing subviews as you need it.

In this class (I don't know how to call it because you did not say it), I would declare a member to store the subview:

```
@interface MyViewController {
    ...
    UIImageView* imageView;
    ...
}
....
@end
```

Here the implementation:

```
@implementation MyViewController;
...

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ....
    [self createImageView];
    ....
}

- (void) createImageView {
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_logo_medium.png"]];
  imageView.frame = CGRectMake(123, 200, 250, 66);
  imageView.tag = 800;
  imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
}

- (void)addImageView {
    [self.parentViewController.view.window addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void) removeImageView {
   [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    ...
    [imageView release];
    ...
}
```

So, in `viewDidLoad` you create the imageView and store it internally for later use; When you need it, you add it by calling `addImageView`; when you are done with it, you remove it with `removeImageView`.

If your class is not a view controller, you should be able to apply those same changes to it.

Comment: Can you provide any code for help ? I am bit confuse in that.

Comment: Sure. Could you post the definition (.h file) for the class that contains the code you already posted?

Comment: The code which I posted is within viewDidLoad() block of my Login page and I want to remove it after successful login at Home page viewDidLoad() and want to re-add it after two pages MainPageController DidLoad(). Any thing more to be posted? Please help.

Comment: I have did it. Please see following code: for (UIView *subview in [self.parentViewController.view.window subviews])
 {
  // Only remove the subviews with tag not equal to 1
  if (subview.tag == 800)
  {   
   [subview removeFromSuperview];
  }
 } Is it correct to remove it? I have again used previously posed code for adding it, Is is correct way to implement? please let me clear on that. Thanks for your earlier help.

Comment: See my edit. How you do in your comment is correct as to removing, but the view would be deallocated and re-created each time. Maybe it is ok with you; my code would allow you to create the imageView only once.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio's advice is good and correct here.  The one other thing I'd add is that in most cases you should only have a single subview of your window.  This is because the window coordinates only with the view controller for the most recently added view to manage autorotation.  Quoting from the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS:

> In an iOS application, the window object does much of the work
>   associated with changing the current orientation. However, it works in
>   conjunction with the application’s view controllers to determine
>   whether an orientation change should occur at all, and if so, what
>   additional methods should be called to respond to the change.
>   Specifically, it works with the view controller whose root view was
>   most recently added to, or presented in, the window. In other words,
>   the window object works only with the frontmost view controller whose
>   view was displayed using one of the mechanisms described in
>   “Presenting a View Controller’s View.”